# I want to scroll only one middle portion which has variable top and bottom bar

Tags: html, css

I have a top bar, bottom navigation and middle part has a grid list. The top bar and bottom bar varies in height as there are lot of actions(hiding div for certain conditions and addition of div for certain conditions). I want only middle part i.e grid list to scroll. How can i set this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Do you mean that you want the top and bottom bars to be always fixed in their positions and the middle part to scroll as you scroll?  Or do you mean that you wish for the top and bottom bars to not have scroll bars?

Comment: @dee share your fiddle (code)

Comment: The top and bottom bars are always fixed but varies in height and shouldn't scroll. Only the gridlist ( the center portion should scroll). Like this one : http://jsfiddle.net/d5jf6/ but topbar and bottom will not have a fixed height. ( since for certain actions i make addittion of divs to display in top bar and bottom bar).